# How to define a class in an ontology with one special relation?

Tags: owl, ontology, rule, swrl

I want to define two classes whose members are nodes and they are the extent of several links.

In the **first class**, one of these links have a type `Highway`, while in the **second class** none of them is a type `Highway`.

I can make the first class using SWRL but the second one is not possible since there seems to be no negation for such an expression.

could I define them using General Class axioms?

something like:

```
Class1: Node and (in_extent_of some Arc and min one Arc is Highway)

Class2: Node and (in_extent_of some Arc and Arc not Highway)
```

Comment: I would like to know why I received a down-vote in less that 5 seconds!!!!

Comment: How would the first look like in SWRL? And what is `Arc`? I guess it's not a property, thus, both axioms have wrong syntax. Or is `Arc` both, a class and a object property?

Comment: the above code is a pseudo code! Arc is a class, so is Highway.